# CSS - I can't align with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with flex. I try align my div's in big div.

I want the 'dol_stopki' went to bottom of footer.

I wrote this code:

```
codepen.io/anon/pen/ogQLgM
```

What I must to do to have expect effect.

Sorry for my pidgin english.

Answer (score 0):

In your dol_stopki class, add
Positive: absolute:
Bottom: 0px;

Or

Of you have a fixed height footer.
It's better you give manually the distance from top.
Eg: positive: relative;
Top:35px;   // give px acc. To your need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the result you're expecting. But if you give the `<footer>` the class `flex` and remove the `<div class="flex">` it would fit to your css selector `footer.flex`.

And if you change

```
#dol_stopki {
  text-align: center;
  align-self: flex-end;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

to

```
#dol_stopki {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

You get something like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEQrqr

Answer (score 0):

what you need is :`space-between` and set the `height` too:

```css
footer {
  height: 70px;
  width: inherit;
  background-color:red;
  font-size: 10px;
}
footer .flex {
  height:100%;/* fills up height of footer */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;/* sprays flex box froman extremity to the other */
}
#gora_stopki, #dol_stopki {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
}
#dol_stopki {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="flex">
    <div id="gora_stopki">Strona została utworzona poprzez zastosowanie <a href="#">HTML5</a> i <a href="#">CSS3</a>
      <br>Walidacja HTML5 | Waliacja CSS
    </div>
    <div id="dol_stopki">
      Projektujemy I Wykonujemy <a href="#">Strony Internetowe</a>|<a href="#">Sklepy Internetowe</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

some more info https://css-tricks.com/search-results/?q=flex